# How to print only an IP address list of traceroute?

Tags: unix, terminal, grep, traceroute

How do I print only an IP address list of a `traceroute` run?

I don't want the web addresses like `something-online.net` and their round trip times.

How do I get a "simple" `traceroute` from the terminal?

Comment: You need to add an example of what output you're currently seeing and what you are looking for.  This is too vague.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you looking for `traceroute -n`?  From the `man` page:

```
   -n     Do not try to map IP addresses to  host  names  when  displaying
          them.
```

**Edit:** Comment added further requirement of removing round trip times.

To display everything except round trip times (sequence and IP address), CSV-formatted:

```
traceroute -n 8.8.8.8 | tail -n+2 | awk '{ print $1 "," $2 }'
```

Comment: yes, but how do I out it to a csv file without the round trip times in ms?

Comment: Pipe the output into awk to print only the IP columns.

Answer (score 1):

Building on Dave Sherohman's answer. As I'm using using MinGW64, I only have access to `tracert` and not `traceroute`.

`tracert` uses the `-d` flag instead of the `-n` flag:

```
  -d                 Do not resolve addresses to hostnames.
```

And, here's some example output:

```
$ tracert -d 8.8.8.8 | tail -n+2 | awk '{ print $8 }'
of

10.7.7.1
169.57.0.194
169.57.118.132
50.97.19.110
50.97.19.113
50.97.16.37

108.170.231.15
8.8.8.8
```